# Mosaico: Unable to drag and drop images into Versafix template

Tags: mosaico

I'm running civiCRM 5.28.3 on Joomla 3.9.21 with Mosaico version 2.5.159...

When I try to drag an image into a content block, the dropzone in the content block resolves to a small square, and I cannot drop the image into the content block.

Here's a short video showing the issue:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/v0wzy3ttw6crv1m/Mosaico%20images%202020-08-27_15-24-53.MP4?dl=0

Anyone have some insights into how to resolve this (or how to debug it)?

Comment: Can you check browser console for any error

Comment: I have a few errors...

https://www.dropbox.com/s/vru1uzmvvvi9b4v/Console%202020-08-27_15-55-21.png?dl=0

Comment: Check your resource url in civi

Comment: Will do that now... Looking at the paths to the the JS files, seems a bit odd, as they point to a folder that doesn't exist:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/l4duxmguvib64sx/Mosaico%202020-08-27_16-03-27.MP4?dl=0

Comment: Resource URLs look fine to me:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/7tpdxhiv7bh4wy1/Mosaico%202020-08-27_16-06-13.png?dl=0

Comment: What is your mosaico version?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112355/discussion-between-pradeep-nayak-and-a-block).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are in Joomla and want to edit the mosaico template, than make sure that you are logged in front end and backend of the website.

HTH

Pradeep

Answer (score 0):

We found some sites where drag-and-drop stopped working post-upgrade started again once we did an extra cv flush (sorry if that is drupal speak - you can do via the UI too) - just in case it is as simple as that for you

(Edit) Hmm actually the above was for a separate post-upgrade Mosaico issue, the one relating to drag-drop images stopping was related to some path weirdness which resolved once we upgraded all other plugins (it was a WP site)